# Rename file using its id from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file-upload

I am uploading image files using their original name. I upload the file path etc. to a database and every image gets a unique id in the database. Until here everything works fine.
Now, I would like to give the uploaded image files their unique id from the database table as a name. (e.g. if the image id is 1, I would like the file to be called 1.jpg and so on.) I cannot get it to work.
My not working approach:
**The database table**

```
 TABLE `images`
 `image_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'FOREIGN KEY referencing the user_id of the user, who uploaded the images',
 `image_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 `image_path` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
 `image_upload_timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`);
```

**The script to write the image to the database** using its original name (working):

```
$database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

$sql = "INSERT INTO images VALUES ('', :user_id, :image_name, :image_path, :image_upload_timestamp)";
$query = $database->prepare($sql);

$query->execute(array(':user_id' => Session::get('user_id'), 
                      ':image_name' => $file_name, 
                      ':image_path' => $file_destination, 
                      ':image_upload_timestamp' => time()));

ImageModel::renameImage($image_id);
```

**The renameImage method (not working!)**

```
public static function renameImage($image_id)
    {   
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

        $query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id = :image_id AND user_id = :user_id");
        $query->execute(array(':image_id' => $image_id, ':user_id' => Session::get('user_id')));

        $img_id = $query->fetch();

        // Convert array to string
        $file_name = $img_id->image_id;

        $image_name = $file_name . '.jpg';


        $sql = "UPDATE images SET image_name = :image_name WHERE :image_id = $image_id";
        $sth = $database->prepare($sql);

        $sth->execute(array(':image_name' => $image_name));
    }
```

I am really new to this and would highly appreciate any kind of help! Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, the files are uploaded with their original name like the renameImage method would not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there in the code that you show aren't any  related with files, assuming that you are doing the file upload in other place, you just need to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
rename($img_id->image_path.$img_id->image_path, $img_id->image_path.$image_name);

$sql = "UPDATE images SET image_name = :image_name WHERE image_id = :image_id";
$sth = $database->prepare($sql);

$sth->execute(array(':image_name' => $image_name,
                    ':image_id' =>  $img_id ));
```

Comment: Still the same outcome. The images are uploaded with their originial name.

Comment: wen you said "The images are uploaded with their originial name" are you talking about the file in your server?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to rest of the thing in this function as well. This function only changed the image name in DB not for uploaded image name.

```
public static function renameImage($image_id)
    {   
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
        $file_name = $img_id->image_id;
        $image_name = $image_id. '.jpg';
        $sql = "UPDATE images SET image_name = :image_name WHERE image_id = :image_id";
        $sth = $database->prepare($sql);

        $sth->execute(array(':image_name' => $image_name,
                                ':image_id' =>  $img_id ));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem. I have the same outcome.

Comment: this function is to deal with DB only. it won't change the name of the uploaded image file. To changing the upload image name you must have to rename file name follow this http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: I did not realize that, although that is quite obvious. Thank you! However, it does not change the name in the database.

Comment: yeah!! for changing name in DB you can follow my function written above.

Comment: I tried that. It does not work, unfortunately. I think I am not getting the image_id from anywhere. Thank you so much for your help so far!!